# Add <br> after every tag/element with a particular class

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to insert a break element into my markup after every element with a class 'record'?

Example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="block" id="codeBlock">
<div class="record">t1</div>
<div class="record">t2</div>
<div class="tlast">
 <div class="record"></div>
     <div class="record">x1</div>
     <div class="record">x2</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('codeBlock')
```

I have the whole element, now I want to add a break tag after every tag with class 'record' no matter how deep it goes without using jQuery.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot do your style related change using css?

Comment: I am using a library that doen't really render up any css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `insertBefore`

```
Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( ".record" ) ).forEach( function(ele){
    ele.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement("br"), ele.nextSibling);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using Core JavaScript. I would suggest using JQuery for this to look more simple

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#codeBlock').each(function(e) {
             $( "<br />" ).insertAfter( 'div' );
        });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block" id="codeBlock">
<div class="record">t1</div>
<div class="record">t2</div>
<div class="tlast">
 <div class="record"></div>
     <div class="record">x1</div>
     <div class="record">x2</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!